# PageHeap does not show exact crash location

Tags: c++, memory-management, windbg, pageheap

I am using PageHeap to identify heap corruption.  My application has a heap corruption. But the application breaks(due to crash) when it creates an stl object for a string passed to a method. I cannot see any visible memory issues near the crash location. I enabled full page heap for detecting heap corruption and  /RTCs for detcting stack corruption.

*What should I do to break at the exact location where the heap corruption occurs?*

Comment: what made you think you have heap corruption?  If enabling page heap didn't crash at the spot where you suspect heap was corrupted, maybe you have a different problem.  Are you using catch(...) in your application, this would actually catch access violations so your app wouldn't actually crash at that spot.  After you enable page heap, did you use a debugger to run the app? (VS in dev environment or adplus in production environment)

Comment: @DXM: I started to get the issue frequently after enabling /RTCs option. I disabled all ctach(...). I am using VS dev enviromentfor debugging

Answer (score 1):

Enabling FULL pageheap can increase the chances of the debugger catching a heap corruption as it's happening:

```
gflags /p /enable /full <processname>
```

Also, if you can find out what address is getting overwritten, you can set up a breakpoint on memory access in windbg. Not sure if the VS debugger has the same feature.

Answer (score 1):

*Pageheap* does not always detect heap corruption exactly at the moment when it occurs.

*Pageheap* inserts an invalid page right after allocations. So whenever you overrun an allocated block you get an AV. But there are other possible cases. One example is writing just before an allocated block corrupting heap block header data structure. Heap block header is a valid writable memory (most likely in the same page with the allocated block). Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
    void* block = malloc(100);
    int* intPtr = (int*)block;

    *(intPtr-1) = 0x12345; // no crash

    free(block); // crash

    return 0;
}
```

So writing some garbage just before the allocated block passes just fine. With *Pageheap* enabled the example breaks inside `free()` call. Here is the call stack:

```
    verifier.dll!_VerifierStopMessage@40()  + 0x206 bytes   
    verifier.dll!_AVrfpDphReportCorruptedBlock@16()  + 0x239 bytes  
    verifier.dll!_AVrfpDphCheckNormalHeapBlock@16()  + 0x11a bytes  
    verifier.dll!_AVrfpDphNormalHeapFree@16()  + 0x22 bytes 
    verifier.dll!_AVrfDebugPageHeapFree@12()  + 0xe3 bytes  
    ntdll.dll!_RtlDebugFreeHeap@12()  + 0x2f bytes  
    ntdll.dll!@RtlpFreeHeap@16()  + 0x36919 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12()  + 0x722 bytes  
    heapripper.exe!free(void * pBlock=0x0603bf98)  Line 110 C
>   heapripper.exe!main()  Line 11 + 0x9 bytes  C++
    heapripper.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 266 + 0x12 bytes   C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0xe bytes 
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

*Pageheap* enables rigorous heap consistency checks, but the checks do not kick in untill some other heap API is called. The check routines are seen on stack. (Without *Pageheap* the application would probably just AV in heap implementation attempting to use an invalid pointer.)

So *Pageheap* does not give you 100% guarantee to catch a corruption exactly at the moment when it occurs. You need tools like *Purify* or *Valgrind* that track every memory access.

Don't get me wrong, I think *Pageheap* is still very useful. It causes much less performance degradation compared to the mentioned *Purify* and *Valgrind*, so it allows running much more complex scenarios.